# Resharper DotCover behaving different than normal UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, dotcover

Are there any differences between a "normal" UnitTest and a Test with DotCover activated besides the "covered line-counting" ?

Context: Running a specific UnitTest is green. DotCover makes the test fail.
The reason is, `System.Environment.UserName` in DotCover is `null`, while in a UnitTest-run it is the actual current username.

Why is that?

This is a heavy shortened example of the code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void MyTest(){
      var test = System.Environment.UserName;
      Assert.AreEqual(test, "User");
    }
```

UnitTest: Assert is true

DotCover: Assert is false

Comment: Does this behavior occur when you run the single test, or only when you run a test suite? Background: insufficient clean-up after a test may result in some "global" state being changed, and the order of test may vary between test runners.

Comment: Hello Mr. Hiller, 
the behaviour described above is occuring in both of your cases